# Load different authentication provider for certain url

Tags: spring, spring-security, kotlin

I want to load different authentication providers for different urls. For example, if I have url matching "/foo/something", then load FooProvider and for "bar/something" -> BarProvider. The problem is that when I hit "bar/something" url, the sessionScope parameter (I pass it in constructor of provider) is still "foo". That means, FooProvider is loaded, but this is not what I expect. 
Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

```
 abstract class TokenAuthenticationProvider (
        protected val sessionScope: SessionScope
    ) : AuthenticationProvider { 

    private fun authenticateToken(authentication: TokenAuthentication): Authentication { 
        println("sessionScope $sessionScope")
    }
}

@Component
class FooAuthenticationProvider : TokenAuthenticationProvider (sessionScope = SessionScope.Foo)

@Component
class BarAuthenticationProvider : TokenAuthenticationProvider (sessionScope = SessionScope.Bar)


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration @Autowired constructor(
    private val fooProvider: FooProvider,
    private val barProvider: BarProvider,
    private val authFilter: AuthFilter,
    private val corsFilter: CustomCorsFilter
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {

        ... 

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("foo/**")
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(fooProvider)

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("bar/**")
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(barProvider)

          ... 
    }

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(fooProvider)
        auth.authenticationProvider(barProvider)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and add an `antMatcher` at the top level of `HttpSecurity`.

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
class FooWebSecurityConfiguration(val provider: FooProvider) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.antMatcher("/foo/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/foo/**")
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()                
            .authenticationProvider(provider)
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
class BarWebSecurityConfiguration(val provider: BarProvider) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.antMatcher("/bar/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/bar/**")
            .fullyAuthenticated()              
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(provider)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this one isn't working. Method authenticateToken in Provider doesn't execute. I have one more configuration with global settings (like disable csrf, etc...) with Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE and EnableWebSecurity annotation.

Comment: Every configuration requires an different path and only one configuration is choosen. You might have one at the end of the order chain that matches all, but the settings are not merged.

Comment: I tried with 2 equal configuration, but different paths and different providers, but still didn't work. I think, I'm gonna pass sessionScope through AuthFilter.